# Backspace not working in textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a textarea to gather some data.  The issue I am having is that the backspace button is not working.  I can select all the text and use the delete button to remove the text but I can't use the backspace button.  Does anyone have suggestions on to why the backspace isn't working?

Comment: Sure your keyboard is working properly?

Comment: Does your backspace key actually work?

Comment: Are you disabling it somewhere?

Comment: Did you try it on more than one machine? If yes, try posting an example on jsfiddle.net.

Comment: This sounds more like a problem with your keyboard than the code. Just in case, are you using any Javascript or is it just plain HTML? If JS, then please post.

Comment: 1) does backspace work in other applications? 2) what does your js code do with textarea?

Answer (score -1):

Faced the same problem.

Шt is turned out, that there is a bug in ExtJs 4 with Backspace button: ExtJs App propagates Backspace to the browser and user will be redirected to previously opened page.

Here is some details [Stop the backspace key from going to the previous page in your extjs app](http://www.learnsomethings.com/2012/05/04/stop-the-backspace-key-from-going-to-the-previous-page-in-your-extjs-app/)

The best way to fix this issue is to disable Backspace button everywhere but in edit controls.

So someone decades ago added this code to our project:

```
Ext.EventManager.on(window, 'keydown', function(e, t) {
    if (e.getKey() == e.BACKSPACE && 
        (!/^input$/i.test(t.tagName) || t.disabled || t.readOnly)) {
        e.stopEvent();
    }
});
```

As you could see Backspace is allowed only inside **input** tag.
I bet you have completely the same situation. And fix is also obvious:

```
Ext.EventManager.on(window, 'keydown', function(e, t) {
    if (e.getKey() == e.BACKSPACE && 
        (!/^input|textarea$/i.test(t.tagName) || t.disabled || t.readOnly)) {
        e.stopEvent();
    }
});
```